# Is there any site with photos of photography masters?

Tags: web, learning

Is there some online collection of really great photos of great photographers, maybe with some comments giving hints on the reason of their greatness?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want well-known masters of photography, then here are two sites.

[Profotos](http://www.profotos.com/education/referencedesk/masters/) has a lot of narrative about the photographers, with links to photographs.

[Masters of Photography](http://masters-of-photography.com/) has a lot of images, but the site is littered with pop-up ads, so may put you off

[Atget Photography](http://www.atgetphotography.com/The-Photographers/index.html) is a good combination of image galleries and short biographies on a number of master photographers.  It also includes links to worldwide museums and galleries.

Comment: All great sites, thanks. I choose this one because actually about photography masters.

Answer (score 5):

[1x](http://1x.com) is known for strict selection of photos.

[Feature Shoot](http://www.featureshoot.com/) is a blog with frequent articles on interesting photographers, mostly consisting of photos, but often also featuring a short interview.

Answer (score 3):

[500 Photographers](http://500photographers.blogspot.com/) Blog!

What genre of photography do you like? There are SO many photographers out there.
Also, visit your local art school, and go to their library, visit photography section, get some coffee and get going...

Comment: I do not konw :) I still am searching around for what fits me better.